# How to send e-mail for a huge list using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I need to send e-mail for over than 10000 people.

How Can I do it?

When I try to process using "**traditional methods**", my application send about 200 e-mail, so the proccess stops and shows:

---

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/costm/msp/application/controllers/promo.php:98)

Filename: core/Common.php

### Line Number: 442

Comment: "traditional methods"?

Comment: I mean, algorithms like in the documentation (https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html) or tutorial samples in the web.

Comment: Without any code samples we won't bbe able to provide much assistance. But I'd highly recommend the following. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8028987/50913